# JPA named query set

Tags: linux, postgresql, jpa, jql

I'm trying to create a namedquery with a set that changes 2 fields. Below is what I tried, which isn't working.  It worked fine until I added the ae.endTime and the setParameter.  Can you not SET multiple things in one query?

```
@NamedQuery(name = AttEnt.JQL.MARK_INCOMPLETE,
            query = "UPDATE AttEnt ae"
                     + " SET ae.result ="
                     + " Result.INCOMPLETE,"
                     + " ae.endTime = :now"
                     + " WHERE ae.result IS NULL")
```

Below is where I'm calling the query.

```
   final EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    // Mark things with no result as incomplete and endTime to current time
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    final Query upAtt = em.createNamedQuery(
            AttEnt.JQL.MARK_INCOMPLETE);
    updateAttempts.setParameter("now", (new Date()).getTime());
    upAtt.executeUpdate();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you have mapped your `endTime` field, you should use an overloaded variation of the `setParameter` method, which add the datetime information. For example:

```
updateAttempts.setParameter("now", (new Date()).getTime(), TemporalType.TIME);
```

Here more on [Temporal Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TemporalType.html).

Comment: I had to remove the getTime(), because that was returning an int and didn't match up with the TemporalType.  I ended up using the following and it does what I need to.                                   updateAttempts.setParameter("now", new Date(), TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);